# Eclipse Photon does not resolve imports in test sources

Tags: java, testing, mockito, spring-test, eclipse-photon

I have moved to Eclipse Photon with an existing workspace. I have some Maven projects in this workspace. All projects did not have any errors in Eclipse Oxygen. After opening my workspace in Eclipse Photon all test-classes which import `org.mockito.Mockito`, `org.springframework.mock` and `org.springframework.test` have errors. These imports cannot be resolved though Eclipse is aware of them as I can jump into the classes.

Why can Eclipse Photon not resolve these imports? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Photon is behaving worst for testing..

Comment: Same thing in `eclipse-jee-2019-03-R`, so many bug in eclipse recently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is really a maven project and you are using matching m2e-version 1.9, it should automatically configure the "Contains test sources."-setting and the related settings correctly.

You may have to update the project classpath by right-clicking on the project and Choosing "Maven" > "Update Project"

Comment: I've did an Maven "Update Project" on an other project having the same issue. It solved it. I think this is the appropriate answer regarding how to solve it..

Comment: We just updated to Photon, and all our src/test/** paths are marked with "Contains test sources=No" (using m2e 1.9.0.20180606-2036). What part of the pom.xml tells m2e what paths contain test sources?

Comment: From a quick look at the code: m2e asks maven for the values of https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getCompileSourceRoots() (or the test variation) , which are usually configured based on `<sourceDirectory>` and 
  `<testSourceDirectory>` but it only does that if executions of `maven-compiler-plugin` are configured and not set to be ignored by m2e

Comment: Thanks @till-brychcy, adding an empty 'maven-compiler-plugin' build configuration did the trick

Comment: Unfortunately m2e version 1.9 skips over <testSourceDirectory> and actually turns "Contains test sources" off again after Alt+F5

Comment: Hmm in your comment in the other questions it sounded like you had downgraded m2e to 1.8. With 1.9 it should work. You do have `maven-compiler-plugin`  configured and not set to be ignored by m2e?

Answer (score 12):

I solved it and want to share my results.

The build path properties in eclipse photon have a new option in the source tab: *Contains test sources*. This option was set to *No* for the folder `myproject/src/test/java`. When I tried to set it to *Yes* I got the following error:

> The source folder 'src/testjava' in project 'myproject' must have an
>   output folder that is not also used for main sources

The error was shown although the output folder was already set to a different path than that of `myproject/src/main/java`. To reset the settings I unchecked the option *Allow outoput folders for source folders* and set all output folders again. After that I was able to set the mentioned option to *Yes*. As the result of it the imports got resolved.

The reason is described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/photon/noteworthy/#java-compiler) (scroll down there to *Test sources*). It says:

> For each project, compilation is now done in two phases: First all
>   main sources (which cannot see any test-code on the build-path) and
>   then all test sources.

Since the option wasn't set for the test-source-folder it was compiled like a main-source-folder. Therefore the imports of test classes from dependencies with scope *test* could not be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

For my Maven based project, I was able to resolve the problem by going into the .classpath file for the project and add a...

```
<attribute name="test" value="true"/>
```

tag to the attributes, i.e.,

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You saved my day! Any explanation though?